# How to use input dialog box

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to add dialog box in my app to let the user put his/her desire Ip address.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please put Ip address")
            ------> here the user can type on the dialog in String
            .setNeutralButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    printer = new PrinterObject("134.188.204.155");--->the result text from dialog


   ....
    }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Anybody knows how to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please put Ip address");
        builder.setMessage("");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null);
        final EditText ipfield = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ipfield);

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        // do what you need
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. I'm wondering to disable the dialog, because it always create the dialog when I change the position from landscape to potrait. do you know any idea?

Comment: If it isn't too necessary to support both orientation , you can set screen orientation to potrait in your manifest.

Comment: I have already set the orientation but it still try to create the dialog and reset all the value inside the interface. Is it because I did most of code that to be showed in onCreate?So,it is always reset when I change the position?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Please put Ip address");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value = input.getText();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```